# How come Android's AsyncTask doesn't implement Future?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, future

In Java, I've gotten used to working with `Futures`.  Now I'm looking at Android, and `AsyncTask` implements almost all the same methods and covers similar lifecycles.  But, if I want to be consistent and use Future all over my code, I have to wrap AsyncTask in a stupid wrapper, cause it doesn't actually implement Future.

All they'd need to add is an `isDone()` method, which seems like it would be trivial, then add `implements Future<Result>`.  (added later: see my answer below for just how trivial it would be).

Any Android experts know some good reason / obscure bug it might cause why this hasn't been done?

Comment: The `AsyncTask` class' sole purpose is to make multithreading easy for developers... my best guess as to why they didn't have it implement `Future` is because this is unnecessary information that could have easily been abstracted out.

Answer (score 8):

From reading the actual code of `AsyncTask.java` it actually **uses** a `Future` task and then some more. A `Future` is a task that executes asynchronously on the go. An `AsyncTask` is scheduled on a queue for a single (or pool of) background thread(s).

An `AsyncTask` is actually more "superior" than a `Future` task. It does fancy scheduling and optimizations on top of `Future`'s functionality. Just look at the API introduction levels. `Future` was introduced right from the start API 1.0. The `AsyncTask` object was introduced in API 3.

An AsyncTask has-a Future task, not is-a Future.

[AsyncTask.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java)

```
/**
 * Creates a new asynchronous task. This constructor must be invoked on the UI thread.
 */
public AsyncTask() {
    mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
        public Result call() throws Exception {
            mTaskInvoked.set(true);

            Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            //noinspection unchecked
            return postResult(doInBackground(mParams));
        }
    };

    mFuture = new FutureTask<Result>(mWorker) {
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                postResultIfNotInvoked(get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                android.util.Log.w(LOG_TAG, e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("An error occured while executing doInBackground()",
                        e.getCause());
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                postResultIfNotInvoked(null);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: A `FutureTask` is not a `Future`, though a `Future` is a subclass of `FutureTask`. You seem to have confused these two.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it seems *you* may have confused the two http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html "This class provides a base implementation of Future, with methods to start ...". An implementation of Future means that that implementation **IS** a Future.

Comment: Actually you're still confused; the quotation you provided proves my point.

Comment: @MichaelHampton a class that implements an interface becomes of type **interface**. That class becomes every type of implemented interface it implements. There's a difference between subclassing and implementing. You seem to have those 2 confused.

Answer (score 7):

I'm still interested in the theoretical reasons "why" not to use AsyncTask for a Future.

But, for the record, I ended up creating my own little class (shown below).  Just extend it instead of AsyncTask if you want a Future.  IMO, a cleaner way than the @Eng.Fouad idea of accessing the private mFuture within the code.  (But thanks for the idea, it got me looking into the source code a bit!)  YMMV.

```
public abstract class FutureAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> implements Future<Result>{

   @Override
   public boolean isDone() {
      return AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED == getStatus();
   }
}
```

Comment: 19 minutes later... "I ended up creating my own class...". Sounds like you couldn't wait to figure out the answer for yourself haha.

Comment: At first I thought I'd have to wrap/delegate all the methods for Future, which is annoying.  But adding a single 1 line method seemed so easy as to be a no-brainer.  :-)

Comment: AsyncTask has already got a FutureTask field, it is not reasonable to make it implement Future second time. It is a **has-a** relation, not **is-a** relation.

Comment: @yorkw Point noted.  AsyncTask already implements "is-a" by delegating all but one method of Future to the internal private mFuture.  For consistency, they should add isDone() and delegate it too for complete "is-a" Future.  Alternatively, if you feel very strongly that it is a "has-a" relationship, nor are you religious about the Law of Demeter (I'm not), they could add a getter for the mFuture, getFuture().  (And, though it's too late and would break backwards compatibility, remove the other methods).  p.s. love the quote on your SO user page!

Comment: @user949300, for backwards compatibility, you can always copy the [original source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java) and customize your own com.company.AsyncTask and add whatever you want according to your requirements,a and start using your own com.company.AsyncTask instead of android.os.AsyncTask.

Comment: Very good, but I think you will need to hold weak references to Future in this case...

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` is too simple. It's intended for short tasks which may take a few seconds, but for which you don't want to lock up the UI thread. If you actually need a `Future`, your task is probably too complex for an `AsyncTask` anyway.

You can check the status of an `AsyncTask` by calling `getStatus()`. This will return an enum which can be one of `Status.PENDING`, `Status.RUNNING` or `Status.FINISHED`.

Comment: I beg to differ on your opinion versus facts.

Comment: @DritanX A `FutureTask` is not a `Future`, though a `Future` is a subclass of `FutureTask`.

Comment: have you actually read the code and **know the difference** between an interface and a subclass? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/ics-mr0/src/com/android/gallery3d/util/FutureTask.java Here let me help you out, the signature of that class begins like so `public class FutureTask<T> implements Runnable, Future<T> {` Check **that** out @MichaelHampton, it is **not** a subclass of `Future` but rather it **implements** `Future` thus a `FutureTask` **is-a** `Future`

Comment: I pointed to a FutureTask from 3D graphics package, nonetheless, the real FutureTask is just like it: `public class FutureTask<V> implements RunnableFuture<V> {` and **RunnableFuture** looks like `public interface RunnableFuture<V> extends Runnable, Future<V> {`. The important keyword here is **implements** not *extends*.